# How connect two distinct hardware(robots/sensors)

Tags: ros, multiple, machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am really new to ROS.The work that I have been done so far has been in a single Rapiro robot.I want to make a connection between two robots (two rapiros)but I am vague on how the messages are sent and recieved physically(with wire,bluethooth or else).
The documentation is a little higher than my current level ;((
I am looking for a simple but all-inclusive tutorial of connecting two distinct computer/robot/sensor together.
Can anybody steer me in the right direction?

Thank,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211036/how-connect-two-distinct-hardware(robots/sensors)/) by [Sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21550/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the Rapiro and other similar arduino compatible  robots, the best way to do and learn about sending messages is check out the rosserial libraries available. For example in my project, i am able to connect Arduino and raspberry pi by using the package http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino. That package has all the essential communication knowledge and tutorials available for testing to send messages form your PC directly to your arduino and so much more. Regarding  multiple connections of robots distributed across a wide platform. The best available link is http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup.
As it shows you how to set-up a host computer and master in your setup to communicate with the ROS. It's also essential to note that there are other serial libraries bundled with ROS like for python and so on.

---

Originally posted by [tyolan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22531/tyolan/) with karma: 16 on 2015-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21550/sam/) on 2015-06-11**:
Great guidance,thanks.
Do you install ROS on your ras pi or you are talking to arduino with PC?

**Comment by [tyolan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22531/tyolan/) on 2015-06-13**:
@Sam Yeah.I have ROS on both(pi and PC). I use my PC for development and quick testing with the arduino serial library i mentioned in my answer and once i am satisfied i move on to my pi to do the same with my raspberry pi and arduino.